# How do I properly export a runnable jar?

Tags: java

About an hour or so ago I exported a different program into a runnable jar and it worked perfectly. Now when I right click export on my project and do everything else necessary all I get is the window of my program, when I type things in and press enter none of the code runs. My project has 2 classes and 1 text file that it reads. So I did the export with libraries required into a folder and nothing is in the file. Is it because it reads from a text file? is the text file not packaging with the jar?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What IDE are you using, if any?

Comment: No errors I can see, and I'm using Eclipse

Comment: You don't see any errors when you double-click on the jar to run it, right? What about when you run the jar file from the command line (with `java -jar`)?

Comment: The file is call ChurchDirectory.jar, so in the command line would I type is java -ChurchDirectroy?

Comment: You would type `java -jar ChurchDirectory.jar`

Comment: My guess is the problem is the text file.  You either need to use an absolute path in your code _or_ you need to read the contents of the jar file to get the text file.

Comment: iMac:~ blockedOutName$ java -jar ChurchDirectory.jar
Unable to access jarfile ChurchDirectory.jar

Comment: Are you in the directory of the jar file?

Comment: I was not, but I fixed that and ran it from the terminal. It started up perfectly but then when I typed into the textfiel and pressed enter this is one of the first things that came up (there was a bunch of other stuff but it's too much to fit here)         java.io.FileNotFoundException: ChurchInfo.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)

Comment: Ok. Basically, running the jar like that will try to search for a file in the current folder. If it is not found, it will throw FileNotFoundException. For that you need to either provide an absolute path (you can just try to make sure it works that way), or read the file really from the jar. When you are running the project from eclipse, the file is in the current directory and everything works.

Comment: How do I read the file form the jar?

Comment: Forgive me if I am stating the obvious, but have you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html) for the `jar` utility?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use something like [that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) so that you read the file from the jar. [This](https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/07/maven-how-to-access-filesdata-in.html) seems also helpful. Otherwise you can use the absolute path in your file system, but then you will need to place the file in the same place on a different system, if you ever want to run your program there.

The simplest thing to do is

```
InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MyData.txt");
```

as it was suggested in the second link. It assumes that you have your file in the root directory of the jar under the name `MyData.txt`. You can open the jar with an archieve manager (winRAR, xarchiver, etc) and see that the file is there, if you have any doubts.

See also [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-getresourceasstream-in-static-method/) for a complete example (don't pay too much attention to the class loader part - you should be ok with or without it).

Comment: ...so basically what my comment was.

Comment: How do I read the contents of the jar? I would like this to be able to be used on different computers if that's possible, it's not really a big since this is just a small project i was working on

Comment: If you still have problems with that, please run the jar from the terminal / cmd and tell me what is the error. I will also need the structure of the jar - where are the class files and the text files in order to help you.

Comment: @Color09 I would suggest making the file an input parameter (unless this just absolutely makes no sense, e.g. the file is some kind of configuration file that never changes).  You can make it a command line parameter and read it from `main` using the `String ...args` parameter of `main`.

Comment: @IvayloPetrov when I use the archive utility the folder doesn't have my text file. What the code does is read the text file and uses every 5 lines to make a new object which is then out into an array and later I use that array for searching

Comment: I exported the project as a runnable jar and only when I have the text file on the desktop does the program actually work. If the text file isnt on the desktop the program opens and such but I cant do any searches

Comment: How can I put the file in the root directory of the jar?

Comment: @Color09 I was looking at exporting a file in eclipse and I'm not sure I see what you need--you may have to create your own manifest file and do it manually...otherwise I would google "add files to eclipse jar" (or something to that affect).

Comment: I would also recommend looking at [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) is some tutorial. It explicitly excludes files from the resulting jar, but if you omit that part, it will be ok. You might need some time to learn how to use maven, but if you are really going to use java, I think it will be worth it ;)

Comment: Also [this](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) might be useful.